# May Jews fulfil 100 daily berachot by listening to the berachot recited by others?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, blessing, orach-chaim, motzi-yedei-chovato

According to Halacha is it permissible for  Jews to fulfill their obligation to recite  100 berachot daily by having someone else recite some berachot for them, such as having someone else recite kiddush for them and they respond amen? Or no, do they  have to recite all the berachot themselve?

Comment: This is something similar that we do on the Shabbat and holidays, when instead of the 18+1 blessings we only have 7, and we need to "catch" for example the morning blessings of others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SA [284:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.284.3?lang=bi) says that it can work when responding amen to Brachos made on kriyas Hatorah;

> צריך לכוין לברכות הקוראים בתורה ולברכות המפטיר ויענה אחריהם אמן ויעלו לו להשלים מנין מאה ברכות שחיסר מניינם בשבת:

> One must concentrate on listening to the blessings recited by those reading from the Torah and the blessings of the maftir, and respond Amen to them. [This will benefit the one who responds, since his responses] enable him to reach the required sum of 100 blessings [to be recited daily]. (On Shabbos, he is lacking the required number of blessings,29 and responding Amen to these blessings can compensate for that lack) (Sefaria)

The Mishna Berura [46:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.46.14?lang=bi) (and others) says this should only be used if there is no other choice;

> וביום השבת חסר לו י"ג ברכות מהמאה וכדאיתא במ"א עי"ש ע"כ יראה להשלימם במיני פירות ומגדים ואם אין לו יוצא **ע"פ הדחק** במה שיכוין לשמוע ברכת התורה והמפטיר ויענה אמן וכדלקמן בסימן רפ"ד